# Cannot provide inputs for saga:difference using qgis_process-qgis (command line qgis)

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing, powershell

I'm using the following command to find the difference between two Sentinel 2 rasters using saga:difference tool in Powershell (works fine in standard QGIS3):

```
./qgis_process-qgis run saga:difference --A=1.jp2 --B=2.jp2 --RESULT=test
```

However I get the following error:

```
****************
Warning: this algorithm contains known issues and the results may be unreliable!
****************


----------------
Inputs
----------------

A:      1.jp2
B:      2.jp2
RESULT: test

ERROR:  An error was encountered while checking parameter values
        Could not load source layer for A: 1.jp2 not found
```

Other tools such as native:buffer work fine.